# Collapse columns in mobile view but not in print view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to collapse columns so that they become stacked when they're viewed in mobile view, but I want to ignore that entirely when in print view.

So if I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PFSbA/):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    These columns should be stacked in mobile view...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    ...but not in print view.
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like them to collapse only when I have a small screen but it's not print view. So the behavior for print view is as if `col-md-6` was replaced with `col-xs-6`.

- Using `col-xs-6` and the like stops it from collapsing in print view, but of course then it doesn't collapse in screen view.
- I want to avoid using one of the print visibility classes because then I'll have to duplicate the content, and I would only be changing the classes of the `div`s.
- I tried getting a version of Bootstrap without “responsive utilities” checked, and then enabling the non-responsive version with `<link href="..." rel="stylesheet" media="print" />` and the responsive version for `media="screen"`, but it still collapsed in both.

How can I collapse the columns only in small non-print views?

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: @jme11 I know how to apply CSS in print view, but what CSS do I apply to prevent collapsing?

Comment: sorry added an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, my comment was too brief.  You need to set a media query with the print styles you want to use.  Assuming you want the md classes to print in columns, add this to your custom css file:

```
@media print {

    .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
        float: left;
    }
    .col-md-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .col-md-11 {
        width: 91.66666666666666%;
    }
    .col-md-10 {
        width: 83.33333333333334%;
    }
    .col-md-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .col-md-8 {
        width: 66.66666666666666%;
    }
    .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.333333333333336%;
    }
    .col-md-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-md-5 {
        width: 41.66666666666667%;
    }
    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33333333333333%;
    }
    .col-md-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-md-2 {
        width: 16.666666666666664%;
    }
    .col-md-1 {
        width: 8.333333333333332%;
    }

}
```

Comment: I just added another class to the specifiers and now it works for only the elements I don't want to collapse, thanks!